# Sample code on dynamic UIApplicationShortcutItems

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I'm looking after some Obj-C sample code for a dynamic `UIApplicationShortCutItem`.

Basically, I have three static `UIApplicationShortcutItems` and I only want to display them under certain conditions. I presume that you can't change the visible status of a static `UIApplicationShortcutItem`, so I'm looking after a simple way to add dynamic `UIApplicationShortcutItem`s.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the following code to add shortcutitem for you app dynamic:

```
UIApplicationShortcutIcon * photoIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName: @"selfie-100.png"]; // your customize icon
UIApplicationShortcutItem * photoItem = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType: @"selfie" localizedTitle: @"take selfie" localizedSubtitle: nil icon: photoIcon userInfo: nil];
UIApplicationShortcutItem * videoItem = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType: @"video" localizedTitle: @"take video" localizedSubtitle: nil icon: [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithType: UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeCaptureVideo] userInfo: nil];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].shortcutItems = @[photoItem,videoItem];
```

Comment: How do you detect if an app is launch from a shortcut in Objective-C?

Comment: you can check in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` whether the app being launched from shortcut.If the app launched from shortcut, the launchOptions  dictionary should be contained `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey`.And you can clone my shortCutDemo repository https://github.com/cp0000/shortcutDemo,      and get more details.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to detect if the app was launched with a quick shortcut in Objective-c.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

UIApplicationShortcutItem *shortcutItem = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey];
    if(shortcutItem){
        [self handleShortCutItem:shortcutItem];
    }
}

- (void)handleShortCutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem  {
    if([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"takePhotoAction"]){
        //ACTION HERE
    }
}
```

To detect the type of shortcut selected while the app is running in the background.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {
NSLog(@"%@", shortcutItem.type);
    if([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"takePhotoAction"]){
        //ACTION HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need do call `didFinishLaunching`. `performActionForShortcutItem` is always called.

Answer (score 4):

I've post a simple objective-c example on GitHub that add/remove shortcuts to Home Screen.

You can check it here: https://github.com/cjimenezpacho/3Dtouch-home-screen-quick-actions

I have a method on App Delegate that handles shortcut items (based on another stackoverflow answer that I can't found :( ):

```
- (BOOL)handleShortCutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem {
    BOOL handled = NO;

    if (shortcutItem == nil) {
        return handled;
    }

    handled = YES;
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Handle Shortcut" message:shortcutItem.type delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [av show];

    return handled;

}
```

It is called by application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and application: performActionForShortcutItem whether app is launched or not.

And to add/remove shortcuts on demand:

```
- (void) addActionToShortCutItems{
    NSArray <UIApplicationShortcutItem *> *existingShortcutItems = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] shortcutItems];
    if([existingShortcutItems count]){
        NSMutableArray <UIApplicationShortcutItem *> *updatedShortcutItems = [existingShortcutItems mutableCopy];
        NSInteger numberOfActions = [existingShortcutItems count];
        [updatedShortcutItems addObject:[self createItemNumber:numberOfActions]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setShortcutItems: updatedShortcutItems];
    }else{
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].shortcutItems = @[[self createItemNumber:0]];
    }
}

- (UIApplicationShortcutItem*)createItemNumber:(NSInteger)number{
    UIApplicationShortcutItem *newItem = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"type%ld",number]
                                                                         localizedTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"Action %ld", nil),number]
                                                                      localizedSubtitle:nil
                                                                                   icon:nil
                                                                               userInfo:nil];
    return newItem;

}

- (void) removeActionToShortCutItems{
    NSArray <UIApplicationShortcutItem *> *existingShortcutItems = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] shortcutItems];
    NSMutableArray <UIApplicationShortcutItem *> *updatedShortcutItems = [existingShortcutItems mutableCopy];
    [updatedShortcutItems removeObjectAtIndex:[updatedShortcutItems count]-1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setShortcutItems: updatedShortcutItems];
}
```

Hope it helps and feedback are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is looking for a Swift4 version for @chengpei answer, it is here:

```
let photoIcon = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "Selfie", localizedTitle:"Take selfie", localizedSubtitle: "Loc Subtitle", icon: nil, userInfo:nil)
let videoIcon = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "Video", localizedTitle:"Take video", localizedSubtitle: "Loc Subtitle for Video", icon: UIApplicationShortcutIcon(type: .captureVideo), userInfo:nil)
UIApplication.shared.shortcutItems = [photoIcon, videoIcon]
```